# Is it safe to store encrypted passwords in RDC Manager 2.7 from Microsoft?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, credentials, rdc-manager

I am using official tool from MS called RDC Manager for rdp connections and little bit afraid of storing saved passwords (including domain admin credentials) in .rdg file despite it's enctypted. But how strong the ecryption is? Is it safe to use this program for saving credentials?

Comment: From my experience, if I move the .rdg file to another computer, all the passwords must be entered again. So my guess would be that it is encrypted using your user account or something specific to the machine.

Comment: RDC Manager and MSTSC.exe use CredMan (the Windows Credential Manager) to store the passwords (in later versions of these tools - post Win-7), the passwords are not stored in the files themselves.